# File google-services.json is missing when combining multiple product flavors with flavor dimensions

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, google-play-services

I am trying to configure an Android project combining multiple product flavors with flavor dimensions.

Here is a snippet of build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    flavorDimensions "vendor", "type"
    productFlavors {

        development {
            dimension "vendor"
        }

        production {
            dimension "vendor"
        }

        free {
            dimension "type"
        }

        paid {
            dimension "type"
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I am using a google service where I need to have the `google-services.json` file and I would like to have a different file for each vendor, one for *development* and another for *production*.

So I have one `google-services.json` in `app/src/development` and another in `app/src/production`.

When building the I get this error:

```
File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
  Searched Location: 
  <path>/app/src/developmentPaid/debug/google-services.json
  <path>/app/src/debug/developmentPaid/google-services.json
  <path>/app/src/developmentPaid/google-services.json
  <path>/app/src/debug/google-services.json
  <path>/app/google-services.json
```

From the error I need to have the same `google-services.json` in `app/src/developmentFree` and `app/src/developmentPaid` and another in `app/src/productionFree` and `app/src/productionPaid`.

Do I need to have the same file in both places when using flavor dimensions?

**Edit:**

I end up by solving this issue with a couple of extra tasks for each merged productFlavor. I added this code after `android` :

afterEvaluate {

```
android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
    if (flavor.dimension == "vendor") {
        task("copy${flavor.name.capitalize()}GoogleServicesFile", type: Copy) {
            description = 'Switches to google-services.json depending on flavor'
            from "src/${flavor.name}"
            include "google-services.json"
            into "."
        }
        task("delete${flavor.name.capitalize()}GoogleServicesFile", type: Delete) {
            description = 'Delete google-services.json from base folder'
            delete "./google-services.json"
        }
    }
}

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def buildType = variant.buildType.name.capitalize()
    def typeFlavorName = variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.capitalize()
    def vendorFlavorName = variant.productFlavors.get(1).name.capitalize()
    def copyFileTaskName = "copy${vendorFlavorName}GoogleServicesFile"
    def deleteFileTaskName = "delete${vendorFlavorName}GoogleServicesFile"
    def processGoogleServicesTaskName = "process${typeFlavorName}${vendorFlavorName}${buildType}GoogleServices"
    tasks."${processGoogleServicesTaskName}".dependsOn "${copyFileTaskName}"
    tasks."${processGoogleServicesTaskName}".finalizedBy "${deleteFileTaskName}"
}
```

}

This way, for each `typeFlavorName`, `vendorFlavorName` and `buildType` variation, the `google-services.json` file is copied to `app/` before `process{typeFlavorName}{vendorFlavorName}{buildType}GoogleServices` and deleted afterwards.

Comment: Do you have an other applicationId when you build the debug version? I added a google-services.json in the main directory and in one for the flavor I am building at that moment. I think it needs a "standard" file in app/

Comment: My problem is not when building debug vs release, is with the flavor dimensions. I want to have a google-services.json for **development** and another for **production**. My problem is that I need to have the same file in both **app/src/developmentPaid** and **app/src/development/free** directories, it is not possible to have a single file in **app/src/development** and another in **app/src/production**.

Comment: Hello @RuiRodrigues, can you please tell me how to resolve this issue. i try your solution but it not work for me.

Comment: Hi. Where do you have the google-services.json file? On a flavor folder? Try to put it on the first flavor dimension folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I end up by solving this issue with a couple of extra tasks for each merged productFlavor. I added this code after `android` :

```
afterEvaluate {

    android.productFlavors.all { flavor ->
        if (flavor.dimension == "vendor") {
            task("copy${flavor.name.capitalize()}GoogleServicesFile", type: Copy) {
                description = 'Switches to google-services.json depending on flavor' from "src/${flavor.name}"
                include "google-services.json" into "."
            }
            task("delete${flavor.name.capitalize()}GoogleServicesFile", type: Delete) {
                description = 'Delete google-services.json from base folder'
                delete "./google-services.json"
            }
        }
    }

    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def buildType = variant.buildType.name.capitalize()
        def typeFlavorName = variant.productFlavors.get(0).name.capitalize()
        def vendorFlavorName = variant.productFlavors.get(1).name.capitalize()
        def copyFileTaskName = "copy${vendorFlavorName}GoogleServicesFile"
        def deleteFileTaskName = "delete${vendorFlavorName}GoogleServicesFile"
        def processGoogleServicesTaskName = "process${typeFlavorName}${vendorFlavorName}${buildType}GoogleServices"
        tasks."${processGoogleServicesTaskName}".dependsOn "${copyFileTaskName}"
        tasks."${processGoogleServicesTaskName}".finalizedBy "${deleteFileTaskName}"
    }
}
```

This way, for each `typeFlavorName`, `vendorFlavorName` and `buildType` variation, the `google-services.json` file is copied to `app/` before `process{typeFlavorName}{vendorFlavorName}{buildType}GoogleServices` and deleted afterwards.

Comment: awesome thanks ! so does this mean that after the process{typeFlavorName}GoogleServices task runs we can delete the google-services.json file? ie: it's no longer needed?

Comment: You have the delete task that take care of it for you. I was having this problem with google play services version *15.0.0* or so. Updating google services to last version solves this problem, it searches for the google-services.json on the folders of the first dimension, so in my case the ones from _vendor_ flavorDimension _development_ and _production_

Comment: yeah so it basically only needs to read the values and then it moves on. I don't necessarily need to keep the file around for any reason after the process..GoogleServices task runs

Comment: yes. but with the correct flavorDimensions config you don't need this mess